# Purrr::pmap using a named list of columns with '~' function doesn't respect names from .l?

Tags: r, purrr, tilde, pmap

This is my first time posting, so bear with me. I'm using `purrr::pmap()` to map a function over 3 columns of a `tibble()`, to create a 4th column

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(a = as.character(1:3), b = sample(LETTERS, 3), c = sample(letters, 3))
df
```

For the sake of argument, using the below mutate() creates the expected outcome of the simplistic example, but my use case is more complex than str_c(...) - it's a trigger for a SQL query based on the content of columns a, b, c (plus some other data transforms).

```
df %>%
  mutate(str = str_c(a, b, c))
```

Using an un-named list in `pmap(.l)` and `~str_c()` generates the expected outcome as below:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(str = pmap_chr(list(a, b, c), 
                        ~str_c(..1, ..2, ..3)))
```

Naming the columns in the `.l` argument and assigning the function through `function()` also works as expected:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(str = pmap_chr(list(list_a = a, list_b = b, list_c = c), 
                        function(list_a, list_b, list_c) str_c(list_a, list_b, list_c)))
```

But what I can't understand is why the following errors with the warning that `'list_a' not found`?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(str = pmap_chr(list(list_a = a, list_b = b, list_c = c), 
                        ~str_c(list_a, list_b, list_c)))
```

Obviously the issue is simple to resolve by using `function()` instead of `~`, but I'd like to understand why `~` function assignment doesn't seem to respect the names assigned in `.l` for my understanding of R.

Comment: That is because when using `~` to stand for a function, then the arguments ought to be `..1, ..2, ..3`. Note that the names of the input is not an argument. The input is the argument.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this without using `pmap`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(str = invoke(str_c, cur_data()))
```

---

The idea of using named argument is that it should match the arguments of the function.  Here, `str_c` takes a variadic argument i.e. any number of inputs

> str_c(..., sep = "", collapse = NULL)

For that reason, it can be used by specifying the column names one by one and that is a vectorized option.  However, with `pmap` it is looping over each row and is not really needed for this function `str_c`.

Just like `paste`, we can either use `do.call` or `invoke` (from `purrr`) to pass variadic arguments - `cur_data()` returns the dataset and the data.frame/tibble is a `list` with elements/columns of equal `length`

If we want to check the output from `pmap`, concatenate all the elements and check - it returns a named vector which can be accessed (if needed)

```
df %>% 
   mutate(str = pmap(list(list_a = a, list_b = b, list_c = c), 
                         ~ c(...))) %>% 
   pull(str)
[[1]]
list_a list_b list_c 
   "1"    "O"    "c" 

[[2]]
list_a list_b list_c 
   "2"    "S"    "j" 

[[3]]
list_a list_b list_c 
   "3"    "N"    "r"
```

ie.

```
df %>% 
   mutate(str = pmap_chr(list(list_a = a, list_b = b, list_c = c),    
                    ~ {tmp <- c(...)
     str_c(tmp["list_a"], tmp["list_b"], tmp["list_c"])}))
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  a     b     c     str  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     O     c     1Oc  
2 2     S     j     2Sj  
3 3     N     r     3Nr
```

Comment: Hi @akrun,

Thanks for the response, perhaps using `str_c` overly simplified the example - I know that the same could be achieved without `pmap` or in a number of methods using it. I was actually asking why the names in a named list in `.l` cannot be used as the arguments for the function when using the `~` shorthand notation - instead the `~` notation demands use of `..1`, `..2` etc. @KU99 has given a brief explanation as to why it needs to be this way. Perhaps I've not fully understood your answer and that is a more detailed explanation than KU99 gave?

Comment: @NGreen the names you are creating should match the argument in the function you want to apply.  If you have a different function, then make sure the names are matching, then you can just use the function name and there is no need for lambda expression